# How to remove header of csv using apache camel dsl

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, dsl, spring-camel

**Reading a csv file content and generating a text file as output by removing only the header line of csv i.e first line of body.
I am able to generate text file by putting the data but how to remove header/first line from csv unable to do it.**

> > using camel 2.32.2

Since I am new to camel,I have tried some approaches like
removefirstline/remove header first is not there in this version.
I want it to be done in same dsl language not by writing some processor etc.
below is basic code for reading csv and putting data to text file,but how to remove the header of csv and put rest data.

```
    <route id="convertFileContents">
    <from id="_from1" uri="file:{{INPUT_FILEPATH}}?include=.*.csv&amp;moveFailed={{ERROR_FILEPATH}}&amp;move={{PROCESSED_FILEPATH}}&amp;noop=false" />
    <log id="_log1" message="CONTENTS OF THE CSV BEFORE TRANFORMATION-->${body}" />
    <convertBodyTo id="_convertBodyTo1" type="java.lang.String" />
<setHeader headerName="fName" id="_setHeader1">
                    <simple>${file:onlyname.noext}</simple>
                </setHeader>
        <setBody id="_setBody1">
            <simple>${body}</simple>
        </setBody>
    <log id="_log2" message="CONTENTS OF THE CSV AFTER TRANFORMATION-->${body}" />
    <to id="_to2" uri="file:{{GENERATED_FILEPATH}}?fileName=${headers.fName}.txt" />
    </route>
```

***file input:csv***

```
Accident Description,Reported By,Date Of Loss,Reported Date

car hit,john,4/20/2012,11-Apr-19

Crane fell,john,9/1/2011,11-Apr-19
```

***file Expected output:text***

```
car hit,john,4/20/2012,11-Apr-19

Crane fell,john,9/1/2011,11-Apr-19
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using camel bindy and the attribute skipFirstLine.

define a POJO class:
    import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.CsvRecord;
    import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.DataField;

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",", skipFirstLine = true)
public class test
{

  @DataField(pos = 1)
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @DataField(pos = 2)
  private String age;

  public String getAge() {
    return age;
  }
```

In your route, you can unmarshal as below

```
  from("file:/test?include=.*.csv&noop=true").routeId("test")
  .unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(test.class))
  .marshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(test.class))
  .to("file:/test/?fileName=output.txt&fileExist=Append");
```

Comment: I think something like below should work..<bean id="bindyDataformat" class="org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat">
 <constructor-arg value="org.apache.camel.bindy.model" />
</bean>
<bean id="csv" class="org.mycompany.test" />

<route>
 <from uri="direct:input"/>
 <unmarshal ref="bindyDataformat" />
 <to uri="bean:test" />
 <marshal ref="bindyDataformat" />
 <to uri="bean:test" />
 <to id="to1" uri="file:/test/?fileName=output.txt"/>
</route>